# Вывод номера картинки из массива в toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

В приложении по данным массива листаются изображения. Можно ли вывести номер позиции массива в тулбар, чтобы изображению соответствовала позиция в массиве?
Это массив

```
public class Page1 {

private int imageResourceId;
private String mNomer;
public static final Page1[] pages = {
        new Page1("Один", R.drawable.page1_1),
        new Page1("Два", R.drawable.page2),
        new Page1("Один", R.drawable.page1_2),
        new Page1("Три", R.drawable.page4),
        new Page1("Один", R.drawable.page1_3),
        new Page1("Три", R.drawable.page3),
        new Page1("Один", R.drawable.page1_4),
        new Page1("Четыре", R.drawable.page7),
};
private Page1(String mNomer, int imageResourceId) {
    this.imageResourceId = imageResourceId;
    this.mNomer = mNomer;
}
public String getName() {
    return mNomer;
}
public int getImageResourceId() {
    return imageResourceId;
}
```

}

Это адаптер

```
public class PageAdapter extends
    RecyclerView.Adapter<PageAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private int[] imageIds;
private String[] captions;
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private CardView cardView;
    public ViewHolder(CardView v) {
        super(v);
        cardView = v;
    }
}
public PageAdapter(String[] captions, int[] imageIds) {
    this.imageIds = imageIds;
    this.captions = captions;
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return captions.length;
}
@Override
public PageAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(
        ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    CardView cv = (CardView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.card_page, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(cv);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    CardView cardView = holder.cardView;
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.info_image);
    Drawable drawable =
            ContextCompat.getDrawable(cardView.getContext(), imageIds[position]);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    imageView.setContentDescription(captions[position]);
}
```

}

Это активити

```
public class PageActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_page);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);
    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = new PageFragment1();
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

}

Это фрагмент

```
public class PageFragment1 extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    RecyclerView pageRecycler = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_page, container, false);
    String[] pageNomer = new String[Page1.pages.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < pageNomer.length; i++) {
        pageNomer[i] = Page1.pages[i].getName();
    }
    int[] pageImages = new int[Page1.pages.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < pageImages.length; i++) {
        pageImages[i] = Page1.pages[i].getImageResourceId();
    }
    PageAdapter adapter = new PageAdapter(pageNomer, pageImages);
    pageRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
    pageRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
    pageRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(pageRecycler);
    return pageRecycler;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно выводить номер текущей картинки в тайтл тулбара. В вашем приложении есть массив этих картинок а сами изображения где-то отображаются. Вы вытаскиваете название картинки которая на данный момент находится в вашем виджете. Дальше вы тащите индекс текущей картинки:

```
int indexImage = Ints.indexOf(ваш массив, ваша текущая картинка);
```

и дальше ставите ваш title:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

toolbar.setTitle(ваш индекс);
```

надеюсь это поможет в решении вашего вопроса. Удачи :)

Comment: У меня активити, фрагмент, адаптер и массив - 4 класса. Тулбар описывается в активити, а индекс массива используется во фрагменте. Кроме того, в тулбаре я уже отображаю название приложения, а номер страницы я хотел бы вывести на свободном месте на правой стороне тулбара. Это можно сделать? Или если уже выведено название - то нет?

Comment: Ты бы выложил тогда эти свои 4 класса, помочь было бы гораздо проще. Все можно сделать.

Comment: покажите код ваших классов, и мы тогда вероятнее всего вам поможем.

Comment: Добавил код в вопрос